# Is there a way to concatenate strings using reduce function in python

Tags: parsing, syntax-error, eof

li = ['Hello','my','name','is','Neo']
import functools
print(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,li)
*when trying out this code it gives me an EOF parsing error

I am unable to find out why this is happening or how to solve this issue*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You literally just need to close the parenthesis of the print function:

```py
import functools
li = ['Hello','my','name','is','Neo']
print(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,li))
```